# I "need" to get a substring using iterators, not size_t positions

Tags: c++

I'm at the point in my code where I have iterators to 2 locations in a string between which I need to return the substring. I see that the substring function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) only takes size_t positions as parameters. I would have to change a lot in my code if I were to go back and track the positions as size_t types rather than iterators.

Any ideas? I've looked through all the string functions (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and don't see any glaring solutions.

To give some context, my string is

```
eq
```

and the iterators are

```
FRFP
```

and

```
NLFP
```

(where eq means my string is an equation, FRFP is the first right-facing paranthesis and NLFP is the next left-facing paranthesis). I need the string that is between FRFP and NLFP, non-inclusive.

Comment: Can't you make a new string with the two iterators?

Comment: `std::string(it1+1, it2-1)`, if the iterators point at the parentheses. Look at the last constructor for string.

Comment: I like how you said "my string is `eq` where `eq` is an equation" instead of just saying "my string is an equation".

Comment: You could use `distance` to get offsets from the iterators if you really needed them, but as others have pointed out you probably don't.

Answer (score 2):

Let assume that you have two iterators pointing inside a string. Then to extract a substring you can write

```
std::string MySubstring( Iterator1, Iterator2 );
```

Comment: Or if the character refered by the second iterator must be included in the substring then     std::string MySubstring( Iterator1, std::next( Iterator2 ) );

Comment: Or after reading your full message you can write if ( iterator1 != iterator2 ) ++Iterator2;     std::string MySubstring( Iterator1, ++Iterator2 );

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "((hi there))";
    auto lp = s.begin() + 1;
    auto rp = s.end() - 1;

    std::cout << std::string(lp + 1, rp - 1) << "\n";

    int beg_off = std::distance(s.begin(), lp) + 1;
    int end_off = std::distance(lp, rp) - beg_off;

    std::cout << s.substr(beg_off, end_off);
}
```